# TypeError: $.ajax is not a function with jquery 3.2.1

Tags: ajax

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!--Navigation bar-->
<div id="nav-placeholder">
</div>
<div id="carousel">
</div>

<div id="successfulModal">
</div>
<script>
$(function(){
  $("#nav-placeholder").load("newnavbar.html");
  $("#carousel").load("carousel.php");
});
</script>
<!--end of Navigation bar-->
<?php
if($_REQUEST['signupValue']==1)
{
  echo "<script>";
  echo "alert('Thank you for signup');";
  echo "</script>";
}


require "database.php";
/* echo " after requre database.php"; */
$result = home_page_image();
if(!$result)
{
    /* echo 'Could not run query'.mysql_error(); */
    exit;
}
/* $row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); */
/* $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); */
/* echo 'inside php'; */
$count = $result->rowCount();
echo '<div class="container">';
while($count>0)
{


    echo '<div class="row">';
    $i=0;
    while($i<3)
    {
      $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo '<div class="col-sm-4">';
        echo '<div class="card">';
        echo '<div class="card-body"><a href="productDetails.php?id=';
        echo $row['code'];
        echo '"><img src="../';
        echo $row['imageurl'];
        echo '" class="img-responsive" style="width:250px;height:250px" alt="Image">';
        echo '</a></div><div class="card-footer">';
        echo mb_strimwidth($row['name'],0,28,"...");
        echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark pull-right" onclick="like('.$row['code'].')"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark pull-right" onclick="cart('.$row['code'].')"><i class="fa fa-cart-arrow-down"></i></button></div></div></div>';
        $i++;
        $count--;
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
?>

</div><br><br>

<div id="footer">

</div>

<script>

function like($code)
{
    alert("like button clicked");
    $.ajax({
        url: 'insertLike.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            code: $code
        }
        /*success: function(msg) {
            alert('Email Sent');
        }     */          
    });
};


$(function(){
  $("#footer").load("footer.html");
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

When I use `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`
 instead of `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>` the output damaged.
[image]

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>` works.

But the original view of the output is

[image]
`newnavbar.html` uses some other script  where there is a different version of jquery. I don't sure whether this generates the error or not.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I view some answer answer with the same error, but nothing solves my problem. For that I have to post a new question with same error. Is it jquery version problem? Or, syntax error problem?

Comment: It is not a good idea to use different jQuery libraries on the same page

Answer (score 0):

first you should put any scripts in the end of body 
for that you should put jquery script in the end of body
As e.g

```
<body>
 <h1> hello world </h1>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 </body>
```

Comment: Ideally you should get libraries loading as early as possible to reduce apparent lag when they get called on by later code. Place jQuery in the `<head>` tag, and the scripts themselves immediately before the closing `</body>` tag

Answer (score 0):

replace `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js` with the full jQuery version `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js` that works.